# How do I convert a string with no delimiters into a date?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to convert 20170603 into a date. I want to use the function new Date(2017,06,03), but how do I extract the numbers from the date? I tried using

```
 new Date(parseInt(startDate.substr(0,4)), parseInt(startDate.substr(5,6)) -1, parseInt(startDate.substr(6,8)))
```

However, this gives me very weird values. How do I extract the exact numbers into the Date function?

Comment: You want to use `slice` instead of `substr`. And better pass `10` as a base to `parseInt`

Comment: @Bergi As much as I wanted to advise `*1` instead of `parseInt()` due to base conversion issues, I could not conceive of a situation (for legal dates) where this will fail. Can you?

Comment: @Phrogz Year `0999` :-) Yeah, it's unlikely to fail, but that's not a reason not to apply the best practise

Comment: Is `20170603` a number or a string?

Comment: There's no need for conversion to number at all, the first thing that the [*Date* constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms) does when passed two or more arguments is to run *ToNumber* of each of the values. Also, `startDate.substr(5,6) -1` will produce a number anyway, so that value is already a number. A radix for base 10 hasn't been necessary since ECMAScript ed 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second parameter of `substr` function is length of string you want to extract;

```
new Date(parseInt(startDate.substr(0,4)), 
         parseInt(startDate.substr(4,2)) - 1, 
         parseInt(startDate.substr(6,2)));
```

[substr Method (String) (JavaScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/substr-method-string-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

## Using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
const date_str = "20170603";
console.log( new Date( date_str.replace( /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3" ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If using an external library is not an issue. I would suggest using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

There are many methods available. For your case.

```
var d = new moment("20170603 ", "YYYYMMDD").toDate();
```

I am using this lib to solve a lot of challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing by character counts:

```
new Date(my_str.match(/(....)(..)(..)/).slice(1,4).join('/'))
```